# Seekbar vertical but layout is still horizontal

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar

I have an issue with trying to make `Seekbar` vertical. I have read many posts here about `Seekbar` vertical rotation and it is pretty straightforward `android:rotation="270"` but the thing is this will rotate `Seekbar` but layout will remain horizontal.

**Basically it is still controlled by the `width` not the `height` per se.**

I tried with wrapping it in another container like `FrameLayout` but that doesn't help. Is there a way to rotate the `Seekbar` with its layout?

Code which I have right now:

```
 <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/onBoarding"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/offerAccepted"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/onboardingTxt">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:max="4"
                android:maxHeight="10dp"
                android:minHeight="10dp"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/background_seekbar_progress"
                android:rotation="270"
                android:splitTrack="false"
                android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_shape"
                app:tickMark="@drawable/tickmark_size" />
        </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Hey, i am facing the same issue. Did you find out anything?

Comment: @VictorBenetatos unfortunately no. We had to refactor design in that segment and use something else.